# Obtaining Google user ID in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

Folks,

I just started to work on an ASP.NET MVC4 web application. I added support for local login as well as login using Google ID (using OAuthWebSecurity).

It seems the user is successfully able to login using Google ID. When I examine Membership.GetUser(), I see that the user name for the logged in user is the Google email ID.

As the user can log in either locally or using Google ID, I need to have the ability to query my local database using either the local user ID or the Google ID.

I am trying to understand what Google ID is. Is it the email address of the user or is there a unique GUID associated with each Google user. I am guessing it must be the latter case. If it is, how do I obtain this Google ID? I don't see any property on Membership class that gives me this information.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

The username for google is the email address. This is an OpenID account.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a associated session ticket (if there is such a concept) to check how long the logged in user will stay valid? Regards. Peter.

Comment: It turns out email is not the true Google ID. Looking over oauth APIs, there is a concept of an ID. I am digging a bit deeper in it.

Comment: It could be the username you use / store in the database. The email and the claimed_identifier. Technically the claimed_identifier is what identifies the user.